# liferay javascript IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dojo, liferay

Currently working on liferay site and stuck with IE8 browser issue. When I loading the page I am getting the Javascript errors.

'undefined' is null or not an object     dojo.xd.js line 14 character 31332

When I load the same page in Chrome and Firefox and I didn't see any java script errors. 
For IE I could not able to proceed much as it is taking to dojo source file and could not able to figure it. I also tried to remove dojo components one after another to see the whether I can isolate the issue. But it doesn't help and getting the same error. Is there any better way to debug this issue/ any other tools that will help on get more information/ suggestions?

Comment: I am using the IE developer tools on IE8 and taken above error from console window

Answer (score 0):

Is there any data transmission between browser and server. If so, paste here or check for correct JSON format. Extra commas, braces are usually the culprit.

Firefox and Chrome are relaxing browser and adjust themselves.